# Understanding #includes c++

Tags: c++, include

I'm trying to understand some c++ code I stumbled across on the internet. It was the flex demo from NVIDIA with the awesome new fluid simulation and so I peeked a bit into the code. In there, I've seen something I didn't understand: There was a class called Scene in scene.h. It had no includes, yet it used the CreateRandomConvex function from the helpers.h file. Both of them where only included in the main.cpp but it didn't use either of them. 
So my question now is: How can the Scene class access the helpers function without including it? And how does the compiler know where he can get the CreateRandomConvex function from if the Scene class has no includes?

Code:
main:

```
#include "B.h"
#include "A.h"

int main()
{

}
```

A.h:(Scene)

```
#pragma once
class Scene
{
    void Init()
    {
        CreateRandomConvex();
    }
};
```

B.h:(helpers)

```
#pragma once
void CreateRandomConvex()
{
    //calc some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#include "A.h"` literally means ”insert the contents of the file "A.h" here”.

So when compiling the main file, the compiler sees

```
void CreateRandomConvex()
{
    //calc some stuff
}

class Scene
{
    void Init()
    {
        CreateRandomConvex();
    }
};

int main()
{

}
```

As a side note, having one header depend on another already having been included isn't a very good practice.

Comment: As a side note, when compiling with precompiled headers, you can, always, depend on the fact, that everything that is a part of precompiled header, will be included before any other header.

Comment: So a include doesn't mean: if you don't know something, look it up in the includes. But rather: everything that is written in there should be written in here

Comment: But if it is 'bad practice', why does someone like NVIDIA use it?

Answer (score 0):

To include `A.h` in a CPP file you must include the file `B.h` beforehand in that CPP file.

one can argue this is bad practice. But it works.